# How to do git add action like VSCode for WebStorm/JetBrains?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I used VSCode, I can add file by

[image]

In WebStorm, I cannot find the same action

[image]

I have to click `commit` icon and choose what I want to commit. I don't like this approach. Because I want to use GUI to review/add my code. Then commit them in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't select any file in the change list, it will commit everything.

If instead you select one or more files then click the commit button, it will only commit the files you chose to commit.

If you want to look at changes on specific files, select the files, then ctrl+d or cmd+d to look at the changes